# LinkedIn OAuth comes back with InternalOAuthError

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

We use LinkedIn OAuth for our app.

The app is written in Node.js so we use **passport** with **passport-linkedin-oauth2** to authenticate with LinkedIn.

Recently, for *some* (not *all*) of our users, when they go to the endpoint to authenticate using LinkedIn, they get properly redirected to the LinkedIn login page, but the login fails with the following error (this is pulled from our logs):

```
{  
   "name":"InternalOAuthError",
   "message":"failed to fetch user profile",
   "oauthError":{  
      "statusCode":500,
      "data":"{\n  \"errorCode\": 0,\n  \"message\": \"Internal service error\",\n  \"requestId\": \"UR66QV5XEW\",\n  \"status\": 500,\n  \"timestamp\": 1485202895414\n}"
   }
}
```

Some googling suggests that the problem could be with the API and/or secret keys for our app, but if that was the case, *no* user would be able to authenticate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Still no resolution but apparently this problem has to do with one or more of the following fields (which we are requesting on login):

'num-connections', 'num-connections-capped', 'headline', 'current-share'

Once we commented out those fields, the user was able to authenticate again. Seems to be an issue with the way these fields are handled somewhere on the LinkedIn side.

Comment: Any news since then? Got the same issue for some of our users and I am requesting only `r_emailaddress` and `r_basicprofile`.

Comment: Those are scopes - you should also be able to request specific profile fields. In my case, I think it was selecting the 'headline' that broke auth. With my setup (node/passport/passport-linkedin-oauth2), that would be the 'profileFields' property on the options you pass the auth strategy.

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with the headline field with a small fraction of accounts, then all the sudden, we weren't able to request the headline field *at all* for any account. We specifically excluded headline from the profileFields when we authenticate.

```
passport.authenticate( 'linkedin', {
  profileFields: [
    "id",
    "first-name",
    "location",
    "last-name",
    "picture-url",
    "email-address",
    "public-profile-url",
    "positions",
  ],
  scope: [ 'r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress' ],
} )
```